# Lotus Domino Designer - Dialog List Formula - How to show the choices alphabetically?

Tags: lotus-domino

My Lotus Notes application has a Dialog List field which uses a formula to get the choices from a view.

```
@Unique(@DbColumn("":"NOCache";"":"";"Visitor List 1";2))
```

Now I want to have the results show in alphabetic order because right now it uses the order as in the view and it's a mess. But question is I'm not sure if its possible to add that function in formula.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@Sort`:

```
@Sort(@Unique(@DbColumn("":"NOCache";"":"";"Visitor List 1";2)))
```